# Entity Framework : more than one entity have the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to save below object to database with Entity Framework code-first, database was created properly but when `SaveChanges();` gets called it thows below exception.

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'ConditionalOptions' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

Can anyone take me to right direction?

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "components": [
        {
            "label": "Text Field",
            "key": "1",
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": "",
                "json": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Columns",
            "columns": [
                {
                "ParentComponentKey":"4",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "label": "Text Field",
                            "key": "5",
                            "conditional": {
                                "show": "",
                                "when": "",
                                "json": ""
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Id":"1"
                }
            ],
            "key": "4",
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": "",
                "json": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "label": "Submit",
            "key": "7",
            "disableOnInvalid": true,
            "theme": "primary",
            "input": true,
            "tableView": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created these model classes to map data into an object:

```
public class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        this.Components = new HashSet<ComponentOptions>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ComponentOptions> Components { get; set;}
}

public class ComponentOptions
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string label { get; set; }

    public virtual ConditionalOptions conditional { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ColumnOptions> columns { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
}

public class ConditionalOptions
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ComponentOptions"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public Int64 FormId { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ComponentOptions"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string show { get; set; }
    public string when { get; set; }
    public string eq { get; set; }

    public virtual ComponentOptions ComponentOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnOptions
{
    //[ForeignKey("FormId,Key")]
    //public virtual ComponentOptions ComponentOption { get; set; }
    public ColumnOptions()
    {
        this.components = new HashSet<ComponentOptions>();
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Int64 FormId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ParentComponentKey { get; set; } 

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int push { get; set; }
    public int pull { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentOptions> components { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
}

public class EntitesContext : DbContext
{
    public EntitesContext() : base("name=FBEntities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EntitesContext>(new System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntitesContext>());
    }

    public IDbSet<Form> FormDataSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ColumnOptions> ColumnOptionsDataSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ComponentOptions> ComponentOptionsDataSet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ConditionalOptions> ConditionalOptionsDataSet { get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentOptions>()
                  .HasMany(s => s.columns)
                  .WithMany(c => c.components)
                  .Map(cs =>
                  {
                      cs.MapLeftKey("ComponentFormId", "ComponentKey");
                      cs.MapRightKey("ColumnFormId", "ColumnComponentKey", "ColumnId");
                      cs.ToTable("ComponentColumn");
                  });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `ForeignKey` configuration in `ConditionalOptions` model class. You have pointed the same navigation property to two foreign keys which are your composite primary key also.

As the primary key of `ComponentOptions` is a composite key so your `ConditionalOptions` configuration should be somewhat tricky as follows to maintain the `one-to-one` relationship between them.

```
public class ConditionalOptions
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ConditionalOptionsId { get; set; }

    public string show { get; set; }
    public string when { get; set; }
    public string eq { get; set; }

    public virtual ComponentOptions ComponentOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Then with Fluent API as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConditionalOptions>()
            .HasRequired(co => co.ComponentOptions)
            .WithOptional(c => c.conditional)
            .Map(co => co.MapKey(new []{ "FormId", "Key" }));
```

Comment: I have composite key in both classes (ComponentOptions  , ConditionalOptions) and both have one to one relationship with same key (FormId, Key).

Comment: I want to use Composite primary key of   ComponentOptions as foreign key in ConditionalOptions and ConditionalOptions also have same primary key.

Comment: Thanks , your provided solution worked but still I want to use "FormId, Key "  as primary key of ConditionalOptions. Please help me if it is possible.